# How to put a new line inside a string in C# source code?

Tags: c#, syntax

Is there a way in C# sytax for defining a new line? (Like in VB _ )

Example:

Instead of:

```
string myStr = "very long string" +
"another long string";
```

This:

```
string myStr = "very long string \something
another long string"
```

Or; does compiler handles this and does something like; "string" + "string" -> "stringstring" in this example?

Different cases are welcome like when these strings are constants, etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Compiler turns "ABC" + "DEF" into "ABCDEF" so there's no cost in using +

Comment: That seems interesting, so when we know all the string there is no need to use StringBuilder? like sb.Append("long str"); sb.Append("long str"); Instead just write "long str" + "long str" OR @"long str ..."

Comment: erdogany: exactly. Also, "this " + 1 + "string" is converted to "this 1 string" at compile time.

Comment: @DrJokepu: are you sure about that?

Comment: When the strings are known at compile time, the compiler replaces the concatenation with a single string.You can easily check this by create a simple class and using ildasm to look at the assembly.

Comment: That works because all of the string elements being concatenated are known at compile time.

Comment: But what about DrJokepu's example where two strings are concatenated with an integer?

Comment: "this " + 1 + "string" is NOT converted to "this 1 string" at compile time.  Try compiling it and then check the assembly with .NET Reflector.

Answer (score 19):

You can use

```
string myStr = @"very long string
another long string";
```

@" is the beginning of a string literal and this kind of string does not end until the next " character is found.

There is not an exact syntax for c# which does the same thing as _ character in vb. So if you want to avoid including a new line, you must manually connect your strings on different lines.

Comment: That's correct, but you have to take care that you do not indent the second line. Otherwise the whitespace (spaces or tab characters) will be part of the resulting string.

Comment: Oh, and the newline character will also be part of the resulting string.

Comment: "Oh, and the newline character will also be part of the resulting string", a yes, this is not nice. For my case not a big deal it is ok, but so this can not do it like _ in VB.

Comment: This is the incorrect answer - the answer is just to use the first code snippet since the compiler concatenates the literals.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is the C# line continuation character.

Stop looking.  There is none.  In C# a line ends when a semicolon ";" is reached.

Thus, as others have mentioned, if you want to break up a string assignment, simply use the '+' character.

```
namespace Jaberwocky
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "Hello World! " +
                "This is a long string " +
                "That continues on and " +
                "on and on and on.";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

A StringBuilder should be used wherever possible to concatenate strings as it runs faster than simply using "this" + "that".

Comment: A StringBuilder is overkill for a fixed or known-small number of string concatenations.

Comment: StringBuilder is a waste of resources in case of const values as the question shows.